# Get error say no match for call in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, function

```
 pluginConfig(FixedPluginConfig(".", "createClientFactory"));
```

I am using eclipse, if I press F3 on the FixedPluginConfig, then it can goes to the declaration, but when I do the built

then got

error: no match for call to '(zinc::FixedPluginConfig) (zinc::FixedPluginConfig)'

This is the FixPluginConfig header file:

```
#ifndef ZINC_FIXED_PLUGIN_CONFIG_H_
#define ZINC_FIXED_PLUGIN_CONFIG_H_

#include "AbstractPluginConfig.h"

NS_ZINC_OPEN

class ZINC_EXPORT FixedPluginConfig : public AbstractPluginConfig {

public:

    FixedPluginConfig(const std::string& configSpec);
    FixedPluginConfig(const std::string& libraryName, const std::string& createFunctionName);
    FixedPluginConfig(const std::string& libraryName, const std::string& createFunctionName, const std::string& createParameters);
};

NS_ZINC_CLOSE


#endif /* ZINC_FIXED_PLUGIN_CONFIG_H_ */
```

Here is the cpp file:

```
#include "../include/FixedPluginConfig.h"
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

NS_ZINC_OPEN

FixedPluginConfig::FixedPluginConfig(const std::string& libraryName, const std::string& createFunctionName) :
    AbstractPluginConfig(libraryName, createFunctionName, "") {

}

FixedPluginConfig::FixedPluginConfig(const std::string& libraryName, const std::string& createFunctionName, const std::string& createParameters) :
    AbstractPluginConfig(libraryName, createFunctionName, createParameters) {

}

/**
 * Construct a FixedPluginConfig by parsing the config file specifier string
 *
 * FixedPluginConfig string spec is of the form:
 *
 *   library_name function_name
 *   library_name function_name parameter [parameter]*
 *   library_name function_name(parameter parameter ...)
 */
FixedPluginConfig::FixedPluginConfig(const std::string &configSpec)
{

    boost::char_separator<char> sep(", ()");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tok(configSpec, sep);
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >::iterator i = tok.begin();

    libraryName = *i++;
    createFunctionName = *i++;
    createParameters.clear();
    while (i != tok.end())
    {
        createParameters = createParameters.append(*i++);
        if (i != tok.end())
            createParameters = createParameters.append(" ");
    }
}


NS_ZINC_CLOSE
```

Comment: Show the FixedPluginConfig class...

Comment: @MarcGlisse has add the code, plz refer to above

Comment: are functions `FixedPluginConfig` defined anywhere?

Comment: @billz yes, I am using eclipse, if I press F3 on the FixedPluginConfig, then it can goes to the declaration, but it does not work when building

Comment: @user1853170 do you have FixPluginConfig.cpp file?

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ we really can't help you if we don't know what pluginConfig and AbstractPluginConfig are.

Comment: @MarcGlisse in fact, I think maybe there does not matter about the content of the code, the problems is that the eclipse can find the function declaration, but when I build it says no match call....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked Eclipse to find the *class definition*, and it found it.
Your problem lies in `pluginConfig`.

I'm guessing you have written

```
FixedPluginConfig pluginConfig;
pluginConfig(FixedPluginConfig(".", "createClientFactory"));
```

which won't work, because a `FixedPluginConfig` isn't something that can be called with a `FixedPluginConfig` argument. Hence the "no match for call" error message.

What you probably mean is

```
FixedPluginConfig pluginConfig(".", "createClientFactory");
```